# Is my convolution of a normal r.v with an adjusted bernoulli correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convolution

I have this problem on a past exam where I'm trying to find the convolution of $X\sim N(1,2)$ and $Y$ where $Y$ has pdf $P(Y=-1)=P(Y=1) = 1/2$. However I didn't get a particularly confidence instilling result.

My solution relied on asserting the following equality:

$$f(z) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(z-x) (\frac{1}{2} \delta_{-1} + \frac{1}{2}\delta_{1}) dx = \frac{1}{2} \phi(z+1|1,2) + \frac{1}{2} \phi(z-1|1,2)$$

and then from this you get the result that we have a mixture of 2 normal random variables. Is this correct though? I was thinking that the result would be tidier, because this looks a bit messy.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &=  \phi(z|1,2)\star\left( \frac{1}{2} \delta(z-1) + \frac{1}{2}\delta(z+1) \right)\\
& = \frac{1}{2} \phi(z-1|1,2) + \frac{1}{2} \phi(z+1|1,2)\\
& = \frac{1}{2} \phi(z|0,2) + \frac{1}{2} \phi(z|2,2)\end{align}$$

Comment: Cool, so my thing is right then!

Comment: Yes, I just simplified it one more step. The notation of having an extra mean for the parameter (e.g. $\phi(z+1l...$) is not easy to understand.